# How to troubleshoot game crash that correlates with GPU spikes?

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, crash, gpu

Experiencing a game crash this is a common sight in the windows Performance monitor, on my system. How and where does one start to troubleshoot the reason for this and solve the problem?

Things that make this hard to trouble shoot:

- It seems to occur at random. I have found no reliable way of reproducing the problem, and hence it's really hard to AB-test potential solutions and be reliably ready to analyze the system when it occurs.
- Sometimes there is a CPU spike and a Disk C spike as well, but that's not consistent.
- The problem seem to be able to manifest itself in different ways from occasion to occasion. Some times it just crashes the full screen application. Sometimes it's milder and just freezes it a bit. Sometimes when not even in a full screen game, it can make the sound of a YouTube video disappear until tab is reloaded. Sometimes it makes music from Spotify stutter and sound robotic. IN other words it's hard to correlate the problem to something specific.
- The reports in Windows event viewer are inconsistent as well

The most common factor between these system shocks, would be what I see in the windows Performance monitor for the GPU. That GPU spike seems to be the most consistent signal I can identify concerning this problem.

I would need some ideas on how to better diagnose this in order make a more quality AB-testing troubleshoot possible. Is there any way to record better analytical data? Are there any specific places in the Windows system that would be useful to inspect? Or maybe, do you maybe know what this could be and have an idea of what to check?

My troubleshooting so far hasn't been successful. Why I'm turning to you here at super user.

*PS; Note the driver dates in these screenshots and you can see that this has been a behavior independent of the drivers.*

[image: Seconds after starting an Unreal Game]

[image: Think I was running Golf With Your friends here x)]

[image: This occurred while basically running nothing and being on the desktop]

Comment: The dip before the spike would say 'driver timeout' to me [which is then followed by rapid activity trying to catch up].I'd guess the timeout is causing the crash really, rather than the spike, which I think is a symptom not the root cause. Maybe tweaking TdrDelay  could help, but that's beyond my pay-grade ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin ah, that certainly sounds very solid. That would imply that the case when two spikes occurs it manages to catch up - but then run into another time out again (likely by the same root cause as the first time.)

Comment: It's a strong possibility. My knowledge on this is only theoretical, though - based on game troubleshooting from my old job, online support. I've never experienced it personally.